# export database neo4j dump from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, import, neo4j, dump

I am trying to import a dump on my neo4j database on linux but I can't. Note that the dump was generated on a windows machine.

I got the following error:

> neo4j-admin load --from=./globssb_28092022.dump --database=globssb --force
>
> WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum 40000 recommended. See Neo4j manual.
>
> Not a valid Neo4j archive: ./globssb_28092022.dump

However, the export was generated under Windows without any error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same Neo4j version?